# Html5 canvas zoom

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a code but i cant get it zoom in:

```
function drawMap() {
    var tileH = 31;
    var tileW = 61;
    for (i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            var drawTile = map[i][j];
            var xpos = (i - j) * tileH + mapX;
            var ypos = (i + j) * tileH / 2 + mapY;
            ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile], xpos, ypos);
            if (i == xmouse && j == ymouse) {}
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get this zoomed in using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ctx.scale`, see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#_Scaling_).

Comment: @JeffreyGearsoffun would you please post your code on jsfiddle so I can check it

Comment: My code is very hard to put into that it uses mutch php functions to load the map, can i contact you somewhere?

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you create a new file and write some simple tests for the ctx.scale method.

Comment: i got it working but i have another problem http://jsfiddle.net/coolking/QsLcj/6/ the tiles acting a little strange while i try to resize them

Comment: @JeffreyGearsoffun you should put the ctx.scale before the loop, since the effect is accumulative.

Comment: ty men :) any way to zoom in images?

Comment: @JeffreyGearsoffun the basic procedure is: 1. clear the canvas, 2. change ctx.scale, 3. draw the tiles again

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ctx.scale()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-scale).

Comment: function drawMap() {
    var tileH = 31;
    var tileW = 61;
    for (i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            var drawTile = map[i][j];
            var xpos = (i - j) * tileH + mapX;
            var ypos = (i + j) * tileH / 2 + mapY;
            ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile], xpos, ypos);
            if (i == xmouse && j == ymouse) {}
        }
    }
} 
this is my code for loading

Comment: You're not calling `ctx.scale()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try -

```
context.scale(zoom_x,zoom_y);

context.translate(somex,somey);
```

I found sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BtPxk/1/). I have not tried it, but I hope this helps.

Comment: I guess, you REQUIRE to translate after scaling.